# Logstash with queue enabled not ack http input events after jdbc input runs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I’m using logstash with queuing enabled.

I’ve setup logstash to inject rows from mysql via the mysql input plugin on startup. Currently this is injecting 1846 rows.

I also have a http input.

When I take down ES and restart logstash as expected I get errors

> logstash_1 WARN logstash.outputs.amazones - Failed to flush outgoing
>   items {:outgoing_count=>1, :exception=>“Faraday::ConnectionFailed”,
>   :backtrace=>nil} logstash_1 ERROR logstash.outputs.amazones -
>   Attempted to send a bulk request to Elasticsearch configured at … I’d
>   expect when in this situation hitting the logstash http input would
>   result in an ack.

Actually the http POST does not return and the injection is not seen in logstash logs.

My logstash.yaml looks like

```
queue {
  type: persisted
  checkpoint.writes: 1
  queue.max_bytes: 8gb
  queue.page_capacity: 512mb
}
```

And my logstash.conf

```
input {

  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "${JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING}"
    jdbc_user => "${JDBC_USER}"
    jdbc_password => "${JDBC_PASSWORD}"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/logstash/jdbc_driver.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    statement => "
        SELECT blah blah blah
    "
  }

  http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 31311
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  amazon_es {
    hosts => ["${AWS_ES_HOST}"]
    region => "${AWS_REGION}"
    aws_access_key_id => '${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}'
    aws_secret_access_key => '${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}'
    "index" => "${INDEX_NAME}"
    "document_type" => "data"
    "document_id" => "%{documentid}"
  }
}
```

Is it possible for the http input to still ack events as I’m pretty sure the queue cannot be full as each event payload is about 850 characters?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get more output in your log if you start logstash with the `--debug` flag?

Comment: Hi @Val thanks for the reply but then I run into https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/issues/99

Comment: Can you provide your debug log?